# Array adapter in android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I've a very basic question here:
I'm creating an android list using an ArrayAdapter which populates data to a listView from a string array:

```
final String[] listData={"Red", "Green", "Blue",
                "Purple", "Orange"};
        final ListView lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        final ArrayAdapter<String> aa=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listData);
        lv.setAdapter(aa);
```

The above code works fine. My question is, why can't we use the following adapter implementation:

```
final ArrayAdapter<String> aa=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.id.listView1, listData);
```

listView1 is the id of my ListView in activity_main.xml. I tried using this implementation but the application crashed.
What am I missing here? Sorry if the question seems silly as I'm still learning how to program android! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You have

```
ArrayAdapter<String> aa=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.id.listView1, listData);
```

Wrong params for the `ArrayAdapter` Constructor

Look at the public onstructors @

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html

`ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, T[] objects)`

The first param is a context

The second param is a resource

The third param is array of objects

So going by the above your code `ArrayAdapter<String> aa=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listData);`

Here you are using a in built layout form the android frame work

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.3_r1/frameworks/base/core/res/res/layout/simple_list_item_1.xml?av=f

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
    android:paddingRight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingRight"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
/>
```

`ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, T[] objects)`

The second param is a resource which should be a layout with text view

The third param is a textview id

Answer (score 1):

> listView1 is the id of my ListView in activity_main.xml.

the constructor is expecting the id of a `TextView` where to put the text you provided through listData

Answer (score 1):

You're tring to use a custom layout with a not-custom `ArrayAdapter`. Android basically doesn't know what's your layout's items, like the `TextView`. For this, you have another constructor where you can specify the `TextView`'s ID:

```
final ArrayAdapter<String> aa=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.id.listView1, R.id.your_textview_id, listData);
```

Answer (score 0):

In ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, T[] objects) constructor 2nd parameter is layout resource to be inflate,so you have to pass R.layout instead of R.id as a argument.And in your layout there should be TextView of id @android:id/text so that android set your string automatically. If you want to give your id then use ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, T[] objects) ;